# Преобразование массива строк в байты.

Tags: python

нужна помощь с преобразованием списка строк, в котором содержатся байты в hex формате, в строку байт. язык Python

Пример:

```
input_data = ['DA', 'A0', '0F', 'FA', 'DB', 'CA', '7F', 'FD']
output_data = b'\xDA\xA0\x0F\xFA\xD8\xCA\x7F\xFD'
```

Я на входе имею данные в формате input_data, на выходе мне нужно получить данные в формате output_data. Как это можно сделать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `output_data` неверен: `D8 != DB`

Comment: да, это опечатка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> bytes.fromhex(''.join(input_data))
b'\xda\xa0\x0f\xfa\xdb\xca\x7f\xfd'
```

`fromhex()` это читаемый и эффективный метод:

```
In [2]: %timeit bytes.fromhex(''.join(input_data))
455 ns ± 2.04 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit bytes(int(h, 16) for h in input_data)
4.47 µs ± 33.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`fromhex()` на порядок быстрее здесь.

Comment: код работает не для всех входных данных если: 
input_data = ['48', '00', '00', 'FF', 'FF', 'FF', 'FF', '67']
output_data = b'H\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xffg'

Comment: @ДмитрийАстапенко: код работает для всех данных. Если не понимаете, почему `b'H' == b'\x48'`, задайте отдельный вопрос

Comment: я понимаю, что это просто преобразование символа в ASCII.
Но я был не прав, код работает верно. Ошибся по входных данных, потому получил неверные выходные. И сначала подумал, что это из-за того, что  b'\x48' преобразуется b'H'. Извиняюсь.