# Строка с байтами в массив байтов

Tags: c++

И так вопрос следующий... Как из строки, содержащей символы байтов получить те самые байты со значениями из строки? Не уверен в объяснении, но думаю по примеру можно понять о чем идет речь. Интересует именно преобразование из например, E9 -> \xE9.

```
const char* input = "E9 AA 12";
...
// CODE HERE
...
const char* output = "\xE9\xAA\x12";
```

Нашел подобный вопрос, однако автор спрашивал решение на Python: [ВОПРОС](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829842/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%8B)

Comment: Например,  `strtol`

Comment: Спасибо, странно, что не нашел эту функцию раньше @MBo

Comment: .. `while ( sscanf(ptr,"%xhhu", & byte ) == 1) { ..`